# Is there an excel formula to find the value between two changing variables?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

this is whats written on cell a28 of sheet 1 on my excel:

`Race 1 - Sunday, July 16, 2023, Sha Tin, 16:00Turf, "A" Course, 1200MPrize Money: $810,000, Rating: 40-0, Class 5`

this is whats written on cell a28 of sheet 2 on my excel:

`Race 2 - Sunday, July 16, 2023, Sha Tin, 16:30Turf, "B" Course, 1400MPrize Money: $810,000, Rating: 40-0, Class 5`

this is whats written on cell a28 of sheet 3 on my excel:

`Race 3 - Sunday, July 16, 2023, Sha Tin, 17:00AWT, "A" Course, 1200MPrize Money: $1,080,000, Rating: 60-40, Class 4`

This is a formula i wrote

`=MID(A28,SEARCH("Course, ",A28)+LEN("Course, "),SEARCH("Prize",A28)-SEARCH("Course, ",A28)-LEN("Course, "))`

when I do this it finds the course length (1200M), as it is in between the words "Course, " and "Prize". I am able to do this because the words Course and Prize do not change.

I want to use Excel formulas to print out the word in between the time and the course, which is either "Turf" or "AWT"

the only problem is the course letter changes and the time also changes, so I can't do it in the same way as the previous example.

Is there an excel formula that only extracts "Turf" or "AWT" from the long string regardless of what the time is and what the course letter is?

Comment: Use the search function wich returns the position of a string within a cell. If "Turf" is in the cell you will get the position. If not it will return #VALUE

Comment: Do something like: `=IF(ISNUMBER(FIND(A28,"Turf")),"Turf","AWT")` for case sensitivity

Comment: FIND() will return the position of text like "Turf". might need iferror() as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have the latest Excel-version you can use this formula to retrieve the text after the hour:

`=MID(INDEX(TEXTSPLIT(A1,", "),,5),6,100)`

It splits the string by the comma and then takes the fifth part --> e.g. 17:00AWT.

As the time always has 5 characters everything from 6 is the term you need.